# How do I prove there is no limit at $(0,0)$?

Tags: limits

$$f(x,y)=\frac{2^{xy}-1}{|x|+|y|}$$

I got to the conclusion that there is no limit, but I am not sure how to prove it.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) when typing your question.

Comment: Are you sure there is no limit ? http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282%5E%28x*y%291%29%2F%28abs%28x%29%2Babs%28y%29%29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Along the lines $\ x=0$, or $\ y=0$ the limit is zero; so the limit is zero or it doesn't exist.

Now, in the other cases, you can write the limit in this way:
$$\ \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{2^{xy}-1}{|x|+|y|}=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{2^{xy}-1}{xy}\cdot \frac{xy}{|x|+|y|}=$$
$$\ =\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\ln 2\cdot \frac{xy}{|x|+|y|}$$

Where I used the known limit $\ \lim_{t\to0}\frac{a^t-1}{t}=\ln a$, for $\ a>0,$ with $\ xy=t$

And now, it is easy to show that the last limit is zero:

$$\ |\frac{xy}{|x|+|y|}|≤\frac{|xy|}{|x|}=|y|\to 0$$

Comment: Can you please explain how do you get from $\frac{2^{xy}-1}{xy}$ to ln 2?

Comment: edited; and see also here, the last of 'notable special limits' https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_limits